# About comparing distances between different frames of reference, and meter sticks

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, distance

If a frame of reference $S'$ is moving with respect to a frame of reference $S$ with a velocity $v$ (along the $x$ axis of $S$), then an event $(x,t)$ in $S$ is viewed as an event $(x',t')$ in $S'$ such that

$$x'=\gamma (x-vt).$$

Let us say we have a rod stationary in $S$; the coordinates of its two ends are $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$. The length of this rod as measured with meters sticks in $S$ is thus $l_{0}=x_{2}-x_{1}$ meters.

If we now turn to $S'$, the rod appears to be moving. At a given instant $t'$, the two ends will have coordinates $x_{1}'$ and $x_{2}'$, and they are related to $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ by 
$$x'_{1}=\gamma (x_{1}-vt)$$
$$x'_{2}=\gamma (x_{2}-vt).$$

The length of this rod in $S'$ is $l'=x_{2}'-x_{1}'$ meters, and we have

$$x_{2}'-x_{1}'=\gamma (x_{2}-x_{1})$$

or $$\boxed{l' ~\mathrm{meters}=\gamma {l_{0}} ~~\mathrm{meters}.}$$

Questions: Are the meters sticks we use to measure distances in $S$ the same as those we use in $S'$? Aren't the meters sticks we used in $S'$ contracted? And if so, then what does the equation above mean if the meters sticks used in the LHS are different from the meter sticks used in the RHS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is as follows: suppose that two friends start at rest with the same stick of length $l_0$. Then one of the two, call it $S^\prime$ starts moving with respect to the other friend $S$. Now both friends do the same experiment and measure the length of *their* stick and the length of the friend's *stick*. What they, both, will find is that, while the length of their sticks (so the one stationary with their frame) remaind the same $l_0$, the length of the stick of the friend has shortened, by how much? Exactily by a factor of $\gamma$.

So say that the friend in $S$ measures the length of the stick of the friend in $S^\prime$, moving with respect to him with velocity $v$, he'll measure

$$l^\prime = \gamma l_0$$

Note that even if the friend in the frame $S^\prime$ would have measured the length of the stick of the friend in $S$, which now is moving with velocity $-v$, he would have got the same result.